# Latest version of jQuery for TypeScript is throwing syntax errors?

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, typescript, grunt-ts

I am almost 100% sure I am doing something wrong to cause this as I am incredibly new to TypeScript and have been updating an old codebase.

When I update [jQuery to the latest version](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery) I get the following errors when I try and build my project using grunt.

> /jquery/jquery.d.ts(279,40):
> error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> /jquery/jquery.d.ts(279,61):
> error TS1005: '=' expected.
>
> /jquery/jquery.d.ts(279,64):
> error TS1003: Identifier expected.
>
> /jquery/jquery.d.ts(279,97):
> error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> /jquery/jquery.d.ts(279,118):
> error TS1005: '=' expected.

I have shortened the paths and not given every single line, but there are a lot of them.

I am building this using grunt-ts and it seems to be using `tsc v1.0.1` – I am unsure where this would be set I am just going by the output when it attempts to build.

Comment: This is clearly the hot topic of the day - a few people have had this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new version of the jquery.d.ts file uses syntax that is new to TypeScript 1.4. Either upgrade your compiler or downgrade to an earlier version of the .d.ts file[0]. There's a "1.3" branch on DefinitelyTyped specifically for pre-1.4-compatible .d.ts files.

[0] https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1.3.0/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Comment: Upgrade to compiler ? 1.4 version isn't already latest one ?